# Can't resolve 'react-addons-css-transition-group'

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie to react.js. I have import React and a UI framework based on React in my project. But when I try try to compile my project with webpack, I get this:

```
Can't resolve 'react-addons-css-transition-group'
```

this is my index.js related to React

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
```

Do I need to import something others?

Comment: which UI framework are you using? Is `react-addons-css-transition-group` installed?

Comment: Yes, I have solved it. I have to import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'

Answer (score 0):

You've to add these lines to make sure CSSTransitionGroup is accessible by your program.

```
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
```